# Holomorphic functions on the punctured disc vs formal Laurant series: isomorphism of rings?

Tags: complex-analysis, ring-theory

Denote the ring of holomorphic functions on the punctured unit disc with a pole or removable singularity at $0$ as $R$. Any $f\in R$ has a representation as a Laurant series. Is this representation unique and does it induce a ring homomorphism $f(z)=\Sigma_{n=N}^{\infty} a_n z^n \mapsto \Sigma_{n=N}^{\infty} a_n X^n$, $R \rightarrow \mathbb{C}((X))$. If yes, does this map have an inverse, that is to say, is it a ring isomorphism?

Comment: Hold on, how is that even a ring? Did you mean to say functions that have a removable singularity at 0 or a pole at 0? The representation must be unique because if $f$ has a pole of order $r$, then $x^r\cdot f$ is analytic in the disc so it has unique Taylor series. The formal ring you mentioned is a little bit in the wrong context because it should include negative powers, but either way it's probably not isomoprhic since the asymptotic growth of $a_n$ is restricted in $R$, but arbitrary in the formal ring.

Comment: You need Formal Laurent series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Generalizations which is written $\mathbb{C}((X))$

Comment: There are lots of formal power series (or Laurent series) that don't come from holomorphic (or meromorphic) functions.

Comment: @donaastor thanks, that is what I meant. I edited the question so it's now correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring of formal power series, or formal Laurent series, is much-much-much larger than the ring of holomorphic functions on a punctured disc... or even "germs" or such, meaning allowing smaller-and-smaller punctured discs. This is not mysterious: for example, consider $\sum_{n\ge 0} n!\cdot z^n$